# Key command for searchable modifier on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

## Edit

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77633169/10001194) for iOS 17 onwards now

---

##### Original Post

One of the new features introduced in iOS 15 SwiftUI 3.0 was the `.searchable` view modifier. Here is a simple example of how it works below. I would like to add the ability to search by pressing `⌘F` as most apps have. How can I implement that functionality? As far as I am aware the `.keyboardShortcut` modifier can only be used on `Button` views which is quite limiting. Is there a way or workaround? Thanks! :)

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var searchText = ""
    private let fruits = ["apple", "banana", "plum", "grape"]
    
    var filteredFruits: [String] {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
             return fruits.filter { $0.starts(with: searchText.lowercased()) }
        } else {
            return fruits
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(filteredFruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit.capitalized)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Search")
            .searchable(text: $searchText) // Need to add key command to search (⌘F)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the same question asked on the Apple Developer Forums, unfortunately no answer yet: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688679

Comment: It's a shame. Seems like a no brainer to me... I wish SwiftUI gave us more flexibility when it comes to these things

Comment: I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70633418/focus-on-a-textfield-using-a-keyboard-shortcut/71930128#71930128) and got a good answer.

Comment: Fantastic solution however I do not like the method of handling of the focus jumping back to the search field each time you navigate the list down or up with the keyboard. I instead used a tailored version of [this](https://github.com/gabrieltheodoropoulos/FocusableTextFieldDemo/blob/main/FocusableTextFieldDemo/FocusableTextField.swift) and that seems to have worked great. It doesn't have the exact same magnify glass visual and the x to cancel search but I made it work without having focus bugs and other complications. I binded `didFocus` to a boolean and just set that to true when cmd+f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I am, 2 years later and we have a response from Apple.

As of iOS 17 you can now use `.searchable(text: Binding<String>, isPresented: Binding<Bool>)`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var isSearching = false
    private let fruits = ["apple", "banana", "plum", "grape"]
    
    var filteredFruits: [String] {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
             return fruits.filter { $0.starts(with: searchText.lowercased()) }
        } else {
            return fruits
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(filteredFruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit.capitalized)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Search")
            .searchable(text: $searchText, isPresented: $isSearching)
            .background(Button("", action: { isSearching = true }).keyboardShortcut("f").hidden()) // some means to trigger the key command
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you all :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to get the underlying `UISearchBar`, and then create a hidden button triggered by the keyboard shortcut to focus the search bar.

The example below allows you to do <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to activate the search bar.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var searchBar: UISearchBar?
    private let fruits = ["apple", "banana", "plum", "grape"]

    var filteredFruits: [String] {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
             return fruits.filter { $0.starts(with: searchText.lowercased()) }
        } else {
            return fruits
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(filteredFruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit.capitalized)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Search")
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .background(
                Button("Search fruits") {
                    focusSearchBar()
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("F", modifiers: .command)
                .hidden()
            )
        }
        .introspectNavigationController { nav in
            searchBar = nav.navigationBar.subviews.first { view in
                view is UISearchBar
            } as? UISearchBar
        }
    }

    private func focusSearchBar() {
        searchBar?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: This looks great, I heard that Introspect can be degrading to an apps performance is that true? Besides that there is no native way to do so right? Thanks

Comment: On second look, Looks like there is no AppKit equivalent for NavigationView, so it doesn't work on my MacOs App because `.introspectNavigationController` doesn't exist for AppKit

Comment: @DennyL. It won’t degrade performance in any significant way. It’s really lightweight

Comment: Okay, I see. Unfortunately it won't work for me because there is no NavigationView support in introspect :/ for AppKit

Comment: Is there any solution for macOS using AppKit?

Comment: @DennyL. Not sure. Would be worth asking a new question, linking to this question/answer.

Comment: Asked a new question linking to here got downvoted. It's pretty frustrating to believe that there's absolutely NO way to do it. I don't believe that, I know there has to be a way because dozens of apples own apps have the ability to press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> and search. What's going on here?