# Focus on a TextField using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a macOS Monterrey app that has a `TextField` on the toolbar. I use this to search for text on my app. Now, I'm trying to add a keyboard shortcut to focus on the `TextField`. I've tried the code below, adding button with a shortcut as a way to test whether this is doable, but I can't get it to work. The `.focused()` doesn't do anything.

Beyond that, I have added a new menu item `Find` and set the keyboard shortcut to cmd-L but I don't know either how to send the focus to the TextField.

What am I missing?

```
struct AllData: View {
    @FocusState private var searchFieldIsFocused: Bool
    @State var searchText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data.notes.filter { searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }) { 
               //...
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("A Title")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                TextField("Search...", text: $searchText)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(minWidth: 200)
                    .focused($searchFieldIsFocused)
            }
            
            //test for the focus
            ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Plus pressed")
                    searchFieldIsFocused = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("e", modifiers: [.command])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit after Yrb comments**

It seems `.focusable` will not work with a `TextField` on a toolbar, so he suggested using `.searchable`.

Trying with `.searchable`

```
struct AllData: View {
    @FocusState private var searchFieldIsFocused: Bool
    @State var searchText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data.notes.filter { searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }) { 
               //...
            }
            .searchable(
               text: $searchText,
               placement: .toolbar,
               prompt: "Search..."
            )
        }
        .navigationTitle("A Title")
        .toolbar {
            //test for the focus
            ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Plus pressed")
                    searchFieldIsFocused = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                }
                .keyboardShortcut("e", modifiers: [.command])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Observations:

1. I have no control where the search field will appear, it seems to be the last item on the toolbar, which is not what I want, but OK.
2. There is no way that I can find to add a `.focusable` so I can jump to the search with a keyboard shortcut, which is the reason for this question
3. When you search, the list get's filtered, but when you try to navigate the list with the arrows (keyboard), upon selecting the next item, the focus returns to the search field, it doesn't remain on the list, making navigation very slow and painful.

I'm sure I'm missing something, and probably my code is wrong. Any clues?

**Edit #2**

It seems this is not possible with a `.searchable`:

[.searchable modifier with a keyboard shortcut](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/688679)

Comment: After a lot of testing, I have come to the conclusion that `.focused()` does not work on a `TextField` that is contained in a `ToolBarItem` in macOS. If you pull it from the  Toolbar and put it in the main window, it works. I would file a Radar on this as this should work as you are expecting. At this point, if this is a search field, I would use `.searchable`. It doesn't respond to `@FocusState` either, but it is a better set up for search than `TextField`.

Comment: Thank you for the info. That sounds like a viable solution, however, how do I place the `Text` and the `.searchable` on the toolbar? is it inside a `ToolbarItem`?

Comment: So, I added: `.searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar, prompt: "Search...")` but: 1. now the search appears as a icon and expands when you click it. which I can live with. 2. when you filter list, click on it and try to navigate the list up and down with the arrows, the focus goes back to the search field, not the list. And, more importantly, 3. `.focusable` still doesn't work. Unless I'm doing it wrong, which is most likely what is happening. I'll try a few other versions of the same, but do you have a good examples of how to make this work?

Comment: @Yrb Added code to the question to reflect your comments.

Comment: @Aleph Anything here? I am struggling facing this same [issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306902/key-command-for-searchable-modifier-on-macos/69308041#69308041) It's frustrating because a prime example of how I would like this to work is Apples own SFSymbols application. `⌘F` will activate search. When you search for your symbol, you can select it and navigate the rest with arrow keys. Why is this so difficult to reproduce its a fundamental feature in almost every application...

Comment: I should also add if you're building a IOS Application then you can use swift introspect to get the underlying textfield but it will not work for macOS which is what I need

Comment: Thank you @DennyL. but this is a macOS app. And no, no solution thus far. I don't think this is doable right now.

Comment: It is not, I ended up creating a custom `NSViewRepresentable` for a searchField and implemented a focus method myself which responds to the key command `⌘F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up getting the following to work on `macOS` using the `.searchable()` modifier (only tested on `macOS 12.3`):

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    @State var searchText = ""
    var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
    var searchResults: [String] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return items
        } else {
            return items.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            List(self.searchResults, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }.searchable(text: self.$searchText)
        }.commands {
            CommandMenu("Find") {
                Button("Find") {
                    if let toolbar = NSApp.keyWindow?.toolbar,
                        let search = toolbar.items.first(where: { $0.itemIdentifier.rawValue == "com.apple.SwiftUI.search" }) as? NSSearchToolbarItem {
                        search.beginSearchInteraction()
                    }
                }.keyboardShortcut("f", modifiers: .command)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me see if I can translate this to work with my app, but the issue remains still that with `.searchable` you can't navigate the list with the keyboard. The focus jumps each time you move down back to the search field.

Comment: This worked great. Now to solve the issue of the focus jumping back to the search field each time you navigate the list down or up with the keyboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71125783/using-searchable-on-a-macos-causes-the-focus-to-always-jump-back-to-the-search