# Using .searchable on a macOS causes the focus to always jump back to the search field

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm trying to move away from having a `TextField` in the toolbar by using the new `.searchable`. But there seems to be a problem I can't solve. When you type the text you want to search, I can filter the list with that text, but when I place the mouse cursor on the first item and try to move down the list with the arrow key, with each arrow key press, the focus goes back to the search field, making it impossible to navigate up and down the list with the keyboard.

Maybe I'm not implementing it right, or maybe it doesn't work yet with macOS, either way, this is the code I'm using:

```
struct AllNotes: View {
   @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel
   @State var selectedNoteId: UUID?
   @State var searchText: String = ""

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
            List(data.notes.filter { searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }) { note in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: NoteView(note: note, text: note.text),
                    tag: note.id,
                    selection: $selectedNoteId
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(getFirstLine(noteText: note.text)).font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(
                text: $searchText,
                placement: .toolbar,
                prompt: "Search..."
            )
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            .toolbar {
                // a few other buttons
            }
      }
   }
}
```

The DataModel is simple a struct of NoteItem:

```
struct NoteItem: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var text: String
    var changed: Bool = false
}
```

Am I missing anything? Am I implementing this right?

EDIT:

Based on suggestions from Apple and other sites, `.searchable` should be added under the navigation view. So I moved that there. The default behavior, as described by Apple, of adding it to the end of the toolbar is still happening, but that's ok. However the problem still persists, the focus jumps back to the search field each time you click on a list item.

```
struct AllNotes: View {
   @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel
   @State var selectedNoteId: UUID?
   @State var searchText: String = ""

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
            List(data.notes.filter { searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }) { note in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: NoteView(note: note, text: note.text),
                    tag: note.id,
                    selection: $selectedNoteId
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(getFirstLine(noteText: note.text)).font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            .toolbar {
                // a few other buttons
            }
      }
      .searchable(
          text: $searchText,
          placement: .toolbar,
          prompt: "Search..."
      )
 
   }
}
```

Comment: This was fixed in Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you are showing the list in the sidebar but have the search field in the toolbar. So you could try moving the search field to the sidebar which does fix the problem with navigating items with arrow keys but I wasn't able to tab back to the search field. And `InsetListStyle` didn't seem compatible with searching so I commented that. And by the way, you are missing the default detail view for your `NavigationView` so you need to add that. Also your `View` structure needed tweaked so you pass the filtered results into the child `View` E.g.

```
struct NoteView: View {
    let note: NoteItem
    //let text: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(note.text)
    }
}

struct NotesView: View {
    @State private var selectedNoteId: UUID?
    let notes: [NoteItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(notes) { note in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: NoteView(note: note), //text: note.text),
                tag: note.id,
                selection: $selectedNoteId
            ) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(note.text).font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
                }
            }
        }
       // .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
    }
}

struct SearchView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel
    @State var searchText: String = ""

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
          NotesView(notes: filteredNotes)
          Text("Make a selection")
//            .toolbar {
//                // a few other buttons
//            }
          
      }
      .searchable(
          text: $searchText,
          placement: .sidebar,
          prompt: "Search..."
      )
   }
    
    var filteredNotes: [NoteItem] {
        data.notes.filter { searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DataModel()
    var body: some View {
        SearchView()
            .environmentObject(model)
    }
}

class DataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var notes: [NoteItem] = [NoteItem(text: "Test1"), NoteItem(text: "Test2")]
}

struct NoteItem: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var changed: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks Malhal. Let me try this code, but as I mentioned, this is a 3 column view. The toolbar sits on top of the middle column, not the first. And I'm looking to have the search on the toolbar, not on the list itself.

Comment: Also, `placement: .sidebar,` this is for a macOS app, not an iPadOS or iOS.

Comment: Yes sidebar is for macOS. I didn't know you were trying to search the middle column of a 3 column view. I'll have to get back to you on that.

Comment: Thank you. It shouldn't matter since the search is being done on the datamodel, HOWEVER, the search field is located on the toolbar, not the first column, or the second, or the third.
I just tried your code, in any case, and I still get stuck with trying to navigate the list with the arrow keys. It jumps back to the search field each time.

Comment: So, I'm guessing there is no answer and this is a bug with the current implementation of SwiftUI for macOS?

Comment: Anyone knows if its fixed in Ventura?

Comment: @MMV I hope it will be. It's been preventing my app from being finished.

Comment: @MMV I had hopes that Xcode 14, macOS Monterrey and the latest Swiftui 5.7 would fix this, but no...

Comment: Had not tried it yet, thanks for the heads up. Maybe point release, crossing fingers.