How to disable searchable autofocus on TextEditor exit?
Every time on exit from .popover TextField (escape or .popover outside click) cursor automatically appears in search field. How to disable that cursor "jumping" behaviour for .searchable field?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var showPopoverComment = false
    @State var comment: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("child button", action: {showPopoverComment = true})
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar, prompt: "Search")
        .popover(isPresented: $showPopoverComment) {
            TextEditor(text: $comment)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
    }
}



try using @FocusState,see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/FocusState

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71125783/5133585

Thanks to the @workingdog.
Adding fake TextEditor(text: .constant("")).focused($isFocused).frame(width: 0, height: 0), @FocusState and .interactiveDismissDisabled(true) helped.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var showPopoverComment = false
    @State var comment: String = ""
    
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("button", action: {showPopoverComment = true})
            
            TextEditor(text: .constant(""))
                .focused($isFocused)
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .toolbar, prompt: "Search")
        .popover(isPresented: $showPopoverComment) {
            VStack {
                Button("Done", action: {
                    showPopoverComment = false
                    isFocused = true
                })
                
                TextEditor(text: $comment)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
        }
    }
}

