# Focus automatically on searchable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using the new searchable modifier: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/searchable(text:placement:). When a user enters the view with a that modifier, that text field is not automatically focussed.

Is there a way to get focus on the `searchable`? This is my view, it is called with `NavigationLink`

```
import SwiftUI

struct UserFindView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text("Please search")
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
                .navigationTitle("Title")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no simple way to this, but have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306902/key-command-for-searchable-modifier-on-macos/69308041#69308041

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this out of interest?

Comment: With iOS 17 there is now a new parameter `isPresented`

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 17 you can now use `.searchable(text: Binding<String>, isPresented: Binding<Bool>)`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var isSearching = false
    private let fruits = ["apple", "banana", "plum", "grape"]
    
    var filteredFruits: [String] {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
             return fruits.filter { $0.starts(with: searchText.lowercased()) }
        } else {
            return fruits
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(filteredFruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    Text(fruit.capitalized)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Search")
            .searchable(text: $searchText, isPresented: $isSearching)
            

             Button("Search", action: { isSearching = true})
        }
    }
}
```